# How to check if path intersects any elements with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm using [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw a path. I need this path to end as soon as it crosses over any of other elements on the screen. To do this I iterate over path values and each time I use `paper.getElementsByPoint(x,y)` method to detect if anything is in a way.

This is time consuming and I was thinking if there is any other faster option to do it. I couldn't find anything I could use in Raphael's documentation and am sort of stuck so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any way of achieving this?